# Load .gif and retrieve physical dimensions

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, gif, computational-geometry, voronoi

I am trying to load a .gif file and find the physical dimensions of entities in the file.
i.e I want to find the volume occupied by each cell in the 3D volume.

[image]

[gif source](https://github.com/Kafri-Lab/Cell-3D-Image-Analysis)

One could do the following to get the frames in GIF.([code ref.](https://github.com/marcomusy/vedo/blob/cbf6639f2eb10491527beaf7cc3656c797f9fb42/vedo/io.py))

```
       from PIL import Image, ImageSequence
       img = Image.open(filename)
       frames = []
       for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(img):
           a = np.array(frame.convert('RGB').getdata(), dtype=np.uint8)
           a = a.reshape(frame.size[1], frame.size[0],3)
           frames.append(Picture(a))
       return frames
```

I am not sure what has to be done next.

Could someone please offer some suggestions?

Comment: this isn't about an animated gif file, it's about a dataset of *voxels*. please clarify the question accordingly.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz actually I don't have the raw dataset from which this .gif has been created so I was trying to find out if it is possible to use the .gif file

Comment: In the link of the gif source the image shows 10 micrometer in the lower right, I guess you can use that as your "ruler" to measure the dimensions of cells in the image

Comment: @Guang Thanks for the suggestion. Can we also detect the boundaries of each cell? I want to compute the volume and also the centroid of each cell present in the 3D volume. I am not sure how to get started with this

Comment: @Natasha what exactly is your input? If your input is just this one animated gif, then it is very difficult to achieve much. You may detect the boundaries of each cell in each frame, but to do make them into a 3D volume, you are basically talking about a 3D reconstruction, like a CT or MRI, but using only some 3D snapshots from limited viewing angles. Then it is probably a PhD research team project.

Comment: @Guang yes, my input is just the animated file and the raw data is not available in the link I shared.  Actually, even to detect the boundaries I don't have a clear idea how that can be done.  With this data from limited viewing angles, do you think it is possible to find the cell boundaries

Comment: @Natasha I feel you might try to do something with it, but you will soon go to a dead end. Sorry for the discouraging message, but the input is too limited, it is hard to go far. You may be able to use AI etc to get something out of it, if you have enough resource (time, knowledge, training data, hardware, etc).

Comment: @Guang Thank you. From the explanations you have provided I do understand why it is not possible. But since I have been asked to do this task by my research mentor, I alteast want to try some steps and explain why it is not possible.

Comment: @Natasha I don't know your and your mentor's background, maybe you guys are already doing state-of-art stuff, publishing best papers in top conferences, then go ahead and continue surprising the rest of the world; but if you were like me, I would feel it is not practical.

Answer (score 0):

To put it simply you can **NOT** find the exact volume occupied by each cell in the 3D volume. It is **impossible** without the 3D object raw data. (just one example of this that there are multiple cells inside the object that you cant see clearly with human eye, so you cant get their data from a picture)

You maybe able to make a complicated algorithm that can get a rough estimation of the volume of the whole object, but it will be very difficult and the accuracy will be low, because there are multiple factors (for example you cant predect if the object is hollow or if it has holes inside it)

Comment: @Jabber Thank you for the explanation. But can you please add a code snippet to understand what data can be retrieved and where the issue occurs? This will help me understand better

Answer (score 0):

As Jabbar mentions, you won't be able to get an exact value, but with some computer vision processing, you should be able to get the voxel dimensions, and if you know the scale of the image, you should be able to scale that value to a physical volume.

- First you need to run edge detection and some kind of [blob detection](https://learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/) to get the individual cells.
- Generate a [segmentation](https://machinelearningknowledge.ai/image-segmentation-in-python-opencv/) label for each slice. This is a 2D uint32 array which has a unique number for each entity (cell) you want the volume of.
- With your per-layer segmentation labels, you need to correlate the label IDs of the same cell across multiple slices. This will probably be the hardest part, but it's probably ok if it isn't perfect.
- Once you have a segmentation mask for each cell in each frame, you can generate a 3D segmentation mask - a 3D array for each cell, which is a boolean mask (True where the cell volume is, False elsewhere)
- Sum that array to get the volume (in voxels) of the cell
- Scale your voxel volume by the ratio of pixel width and slice depth to physical distance.